# Send asynchronous command over ethernet using tcp protocol in python

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous

I am reading data from Ethernet using tcp protocol in python.
I am using below code to create socket and read the data.

```
import socket
import sys
import codecs
import binascii
import struct
import time, datetime
import array

HOST = "192.24.134.1"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 10943  # The port used by the server
ADDR=(HOST,PORT)
ID=43
cmd=2
CMDm=cmdf.cfg(cmd,ID) # make tcp packet to send over ethernet
client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)
client.send(CMDm)
while True:
    datA = client.recv(2000)
```

I am using while loop to read the data from tcp socket. As while loop is not good solution to use.

I want to read the tcp packet available at socket as soon as they are available without while loop.

Can you suggest some methods or library to read data from tcp socket asynchronously.

Comment: A `while` loop is actually a good idea for this, but you need a way to leave it. There are literally thousands of examples on how to read from a socket on SO.

Comment: You can use python's asyncio library

Comment: @KlausD. can you suggest some options?

Comment: You haven’t describe what problem you have with your code.

Comment: Also realize that TCP is a byte streaming protocol.  It is not message-based.  Your `client.recv(2000)` can receive 1-2000 bytes or 0 on socket close.  You must design protocol to determine a complete message, such as null-termination or sending the size of the message first as part of the message, then read and extract whole messages from the byte stream.